# Jfxtras-Agenda, set Calender to fixed Week

Tags: calendar, javafx-8, jfxtras

I´m working with the Agenda-Tool and want to set it to one fixed Week, because I just want to use it as a Timetable for a School and they want to work with the same schedule each Week. I know that it is using the util.Calendar, but i can't find a Way to set it fixed. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agenda has a displayedCalendar property which is used to specify what is to be shown. In week skin it will display the week where the calendar is part of, in day skin it will show the single day (and if there will be a month view...

Comment: That said, the latest release of Agenda (8.0-r4-SNAPSHOT) has been rewritten to use the Java 8 date time API; the calendar methods are still present, but they are deprecated and the Calendar values are converted to DateTime. Just to save you time, so that when we release 9.0 and the Calendar methods should be removed, you do not need to refactor.

Comment: Ok thanks that is helping me alot. Its a very nice coded Tool btw, really like to work with it :)